# A Desktop Software as a Calculator for Polynomials

Tags: desktop-client, math, scientific-computing

Is there a *desktop* software similar to desktop algebraic calculator but working with polynomials of one variable, instead? That should be able to

- add and subtract polynomials
- multiply and divide polynomials
- give power of polynomials
- calculate value of a polynomial giving value of the variable
- calculate roots of a polynomial of any degree
- work with both real and complex values
- be free and cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Dysprosium Polynomial Desktop Calculator from [this link](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part6).

- It has an interface similar to a numerical calculator (width of the image has ben edited).
  [image]
- A polynomial of degree 20 is solved, as an example (counts from 0 to 19).
- Users need to select a precision for root calculations. Other calculations are exact.
- You might use double precision or big-decimal precision.
  [image]
- Using the calculator, exactness of the result has been checked (within the given precision) at the bottom.
- Using different algorithms calculator tries to solve any real or complex equation within a reasonable time. No divergence will be reported in calculation of roots. Termination is based on the judgment of the users and their hardware. This is when degree of polynomial exceeds 200 and so.
- Software is cross-platform and portable and free to download.
- There is visual help page at [this link](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Howto21.html).